# beginning of the slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, load, fullscreen

While loading my [animated] slideshow I want to show the credits [in plain text] of the co-operators of the show and enable the viewer to go to full [black] screen as is recommanded. Now, these credits have to disappear [fade out] as soon as the first image of the show appears on screen, although some overlap seems acceptable for me.
Since loading time is different for different browsers and also depends on broadband connection speed, clients'hardware, etc., I want to ensure the viewer [client] has enough time to read the credits, say at least 5 seconds.

Logically this seems easy enough:

-page loading time [LT] here defined as the interval between opening of new browser window [which gets focus] and the appearance of the first image of the show [randomized]
-reading Time [RT] for local client [viewer], say 5 seconds
-..SetTimeout variable [ST] adding surplus time, in case  LT < 5 
Of course, here I do need a reference point from which to count, but how do I calculate LT as defined, which is probably not the loading time of the full page'.

1) in case LT > RT [loading time exceeds reading time] I still want the credits to stay on screen, otherwise the black screen  is too boring, or the viewer may think that the show has crashed. [this option seems to be captured by the onLoad statement (see below)].  So,in this case ST = 0

2) in case LT < RT or avoiding the credits flash away before the viewer can read it.
   In this case the viewer views the show more than once [what I'm aiming at btw] and is then cached  by the browser next time she starts the show.
   If so, then ST = RT - LT, which forces the credits to continue superimposed on the image(s) since the page is already loaded.

ad 1) MS Internet Explorer seems to ignore ST, once the show is cached. Since I cannot control the clients browser settings I don't know how to cope with this problem. The beginning of the show is the only place to show the credits, since the show never ends.

ad 2) Sometimes Firefox continues to load the show for some reason [though the images are already displayed] or 'waiting for the server'. The credits are  displayed by far too long, due to the onLoad statement, I guess. So, how do I stop the display of the credits in this case?

My example:

```
function verberg(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
   // setTimeout(function() {verberg(id)},5000);   --have to replace the fixed number by [ST]
}
.
.

</head>    
<body  onload="setTimeout(function() {verberg('loading')},5000);">    .
<div style="text-align:center" id="loading">credits...........</div>
```

View [just the beginning of] my show in full screen [no user interaction is required]

```
[http://www.atelierfransvandestaak.nl/slideshow.html][1]    [Chrome, Firefox, Safari]

[http://www.atelierfransvandestaak.nl/ieslideshow.html][2]   [Internet Explorer]
```

In [1] a live videostream is inserted, which is not supported by internet explorer and so in [2] is replaced by a snapshot from the same camera point of view.

I would appreciate your advise for a crossbrowser solution, if there is one.
Thanks in advance,
Wim Schlebaum

solved this problem myself